# Action button -> small black window with other buttons

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I really don't know how to configure my question because I don't know how this control (if it exist) is called. In my app I've managed a beautiful toolpanel with an action button on the bottom of my view. I need to call/push the small slightly transparent window with other buttons.

How this window is named and can someone point me to some example how the folks are implement it?

It's the same one window as in 'mail' app when clicking on tools arrow the panel with other buttons appearing.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only guess, but are you referring to something like this

[image: UIActionSheet in action]

This would be called UIActionSheet and here is a [simple example](http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2010/04/14/iphone-uiactionsheet-example/) on how to use it.